# Remove List Item From Array MongoDB

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a node application and storing information in MongoDB using mongoose. I am trying to use a DELETE request to remove a list item from an array stored in mongodb. Each list item is an object, for example:

```
"budgets" : [
    { 
        "name" : "check",
        "value" : 100,
        "expense" : false,
        "uniqueId" : 0.1224423
    },
    { 
        "name" : "bagel",
        "value" : 5,
        "expense" : true,
        "uniqueId" : 0.12424214
    }
]
```

I am sending a paramer in the url which is targeting "uniqueId". I want to remove budgets[1] by tageting it's uniqueId and removing from the list. How would I do this? This is what I am trying but it is not working:

```
router.delete('/users', function(req, res){
    if (req.session.passport.user == undefined){
        res.json({success: "false"});
    } else{
        regUser.findOneAndUpdate(
            { username:req.user.username },
            { $pull: { budgets : { uniqueId: req.param('id') }} }, 
            {new: true},
            function(err, data){
                if(err) return console.log(err);
                res.json(data.budgets);
            });
    }
});
```

I want the callback function of regUser.update to return the updated information, but since the information is not being updated it is just returning the original data. So how would I remove the list item containing the "uniqueId" that I pass through as a parameter?

Comment: To simplify this, have a look at [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) as a method. It will actually return the document that is modified in the callback as opposed to looking it up with another `.find()` call.

Comment: thanks for that. I have implemented that instead. I am returning the data however the list item isn't being removed. I am wondering if it has to do with $pull operator and the way I am targeting my data

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with calling req.param('id') for my value. When I hard code the value it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the findOneAndUpdate method ( thanks Neil Lunn ). I also realized that the problem had to do with the parameter I was passing in the URL. In my list the uniqueId is a floating point number, but I was getting a String. So I passed the parameter into the parse

```
router.delete('/users', function(req, res){
    if (req.session.passport.user == undefined){
        res.json({success: "false"});
    } else{
        regUser.findOneAndUpdate(
            { username:req.user.username },
            { $pull: { budgets : { uniqueId: parseFloat(req.param('id')) }} }, 
            function(err, data){
                if(err) return console.log(err);
                res.json(data.budgets);
            });
    }
});
```